# Select specific rows and columns - loop - dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe similar to this:

`import pandas as pd`

```
data = {'product_name': ['2000', '2001', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2002', '2001', '2000'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200, 300, 450, 200],
        'quantity': [50, 15, 30, 450, 20, 30, 40, 27]
        }
```

`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

`print (df)`

For example, I want to calculate the average price and quantity for each year (i.e., 2000, 2001, 2002) and save them to use later. I have tried different ways, but they do not work. I can do one by one but that is not ideal! I wonder if there is a way to write a loop to do it. Pick column 'product_name'; pick year (say 2000), then pick column price - calculate; save, repeat for year 2001, ... 2002...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'product_name': ['2000', '2001', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2002', '2001', '2000'],
       'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200, 300, 450, 200],
        'quantity': [50, 15, 30, 450, 20, 30, 40, 27]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

average_price = df.groupby(['product_name'])['price'].mean()

average_quantity = df.groupby(['product_name'])['quantity'].mean()
```

average_price:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 566.66 |
| 2001 | 350 |
| 2002 | 250 |

average_quantity:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 35.66 |
| 2001 | 168.33 |
| 2002 | 25 |

Comment: Great! Thanks it works nicely. Now, suppose I want to use my own function to manipulate the data (instead of mean, say); something that it is not an attribute already. How can I use it? Thanks again

Comment: Use .apply() instead of .mean() . For example if you want to specify the range of prices for each year you can use following piece of code: df.groupby(['product_name'])['price'].apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())

Comment: How about a function like this? (and thanks again) ```def gini(array):
    array = array.flatten() #all values are treated equally, arrays must be 1d
    if np.amin(array) < 0:
        array -= np.amin(array) #values cannot be negative
    array += 0.0000001 #values cannot be 0
    array = np.sort(array) #values must be sorted
    index = np.arange(1,array.shape[0]+1) #index per array element
    n = array.shape[0]#number of array elements
    return ((np.sum((2 * index - n  - 1) * array)) / (n * np.sum(array))) #Gini coefficient

Comment: This could be done too. You have to define your function correctly and remember that the function's input is Pandas Series. Your defined function uses .flatten() method which is not defined for series( series are 1d, can not have higher dimension). If your gini() function is defined correctly, then you can use the following piece of code:df.groupby(['product_name'])['quantity'].apply(gini)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('product_name').mean()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.